# PySpark 3.3.0 - Aggregate sum with condition to avoid self join

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

Given the following dataframe structure:

```
+----------+-----+-------+
|  endPoint|count|outcome|
+----------+-----+-------+
|  getBooks|    3|success|
|  getBooks|    1|failure|
|getClasses|    0|success|
|getClasses|    4|failure|
+----------+-----+-------+
```

I'm trying to aggregate the data to get a failure rate. My resulting dataframe would look like this.

```
+----------+-----------+
|  endPoint|failureRate|
+----------+-----------+
|  getBooks|       0.25|
|getClasses|          1|
+----------+-----------+
```

I'm currently able to do this by creating a second dataframe which filters out the success rows, then join the two dataframes back together and create a new column that divides the sum of the failed count (for that endpoint) with the sum of the total count.

I'm trying to find a way to avoid creating a separate dataframe and then having to re-join them back together as it seems expensive and unnecessary. Is there a way to sum columns conditionally? I've been playing around with the syntax but am getting stuck.

If I could do something like this:

```
df.groupBy("endPoint").sum("count").when(outcome = "failure"))
```

that would be ideal but I'm having trouble with this and wonder if I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `when()` within the `sum` aggregate.

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('end_point'). \
    agg(func.sum(func.when(func.col('outcome') == 'failure', func.col('count'))).alias('failure_count'),
        func.sum(func.when(func.col('outcome') == 'success', func.col('count'))).alias('success_count')
        ). \
    withColumn('failure_rate', 
               func.col('failure_count') / (func.col('failure_count') + func.col('success_count'))
               ). \
    show()

# +----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
# | end_point|failure_count|success_count|failure_rate|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
# |getClasses|            4|            0|         1.0|
# |  getBooks|            1|            3|        0.25|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was like 90% there but something was off with my syntax. I was able to use this and get it working. Thanks so much!

Comment: I suggest adding the `where` syntax to make this a little more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily achieved by using Spark windows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("endPoint")

(
    df.withColumn("total", F.sum("count").over(w))
    .withColumn("failureRate", F.col("count") / F.col("total"))
    .select("endPoint", "failureRate")
    .where(F.col("outcome") == "failure")
    .show()
)
```

Comment: This is another way to do it, as an alternative to group by. Depending on dataset could be faster. Good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `pivot` on your dataframe to get a wide version of your dataframe where the outcome strings are made into independent columns, containing the sum of the `count` column. From that dataframe, you calculate your failure rate:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
# init example table
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("getBooks", 3, "success"),
        ("getBooks", 1, "failure"),
        ("getClasses", 0, "success"),
        ("getClasses", 4, "failure"),
    ],
    ["endPoint", "count", "outcome"],
)
df.show()
df_pivot = df.groupBy("endPoint").pivot("outcome", ["success", "failure"]).sum("count")
df_pivot.show()
df_total = df_pivot.withColumn("total", F.col("success") + F.col("failure"))
df_total.show()
df_failure_rate = df_total.select("endPoint", (F.col("failure") / F.col("total")).alias("failureRate"))
df_failure_rate.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----+-------+
|  endPoint|count|outcome|
+----------+-----+-------+
|  getBooks|    3|success|
|  getBooks|    1|failure|
|getClasses|    0|success|
|getClasses|    4|failure|
+----------+-----+-------+

+----------+-------+-------+
|  endPoint|success|failure|
+----------+-------+-------+
|getClasses|      0|      4|
|  getBooks|      3|      1|
+----------+-------+-------+

+----------+-------+-------+-----+
|  endPoint|success|failure|total|
+----------+-------+-------+-----+
|getClasses|      0|      4|    4|
|  getBooks|      3|      1|    4|
+----------+-------+-------+-----+

+----------+-----------+
|  endPoint|failureRate|
+----------+-----------+
|getClasses|        1.0|
|  getBooks|       0.25|
+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most efficient (well it's a ties the other solution I provided) which builds off the answer from @samkart.

So know it would just be which one you find easier to comprehend.

```
df. \
 filter(func.col("outcome")== "failure").\
 groupBy('end_point'). \
     agg(func.sum(func.when(func.col('outcome') == 'failure', func.col('count'))).alias('failure_count'),
         func.sum(func.when(func.col('outcome') == 'success', func.col('count'))).alias('success_count')
         ). \
     withColumn('failure_rate', 
                func.col('failure_count') / (func.col('failure_count') + func.col('success_count'))
                ). \
 explain()
```

Explain

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[end_point#1039], functions=[sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = failure) THEN count#79L END), sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = success) THEN count#79L END)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(end_point#1039, 200)
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[end_point#1039], functions=[partial_sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = failure) THEN count#79L END), partial_sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = success) THEN count#79L END)])
      +- *(1) Project [endPoint#78 AS end_point#1039, count#79L, outcome#80]
         +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(outcome#80) && (outcome#80 = failure))
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[endPoint#78,count#79L,outcome#80]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! @samkart's answer is slightly closer to what I was looking for because I still need to show some aggregations across the entire dataset, although I didn't specify that in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Has been run with sample data from fskj**

But generally this give you the idea of what I want to do.  It might be worth looking at the `explain()` of this plan vs the other ones to see what is more efficient.  (Really it's the only way to determine what's' better)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
result = df. \
    groupBy('endPoint','outcome'). \
    agg( F.sum('outcome').alias("sum"),F.count("endPoint").alias("count") ). \
    where( F.col('outcome') != "success" ). \
    withColumn('failure_rate', 
               F.col('sum') / F.col('count') ). \
    select('endPoint','failure_rate')
```

explain for my solution: (I believe the to be the most efficient, as it uses predicate pushdown to remove "success" data early and therefore operates on less data. It also does not require a sort.)

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78, outcome#80], functions=[sum(cast(outcome#80 as double)), count(endPoint#78)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(endPoint#78, outcome#80, 200)
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78, outcome#80], functions=[partial_sum(cast(outcome#80 as double)), partial_count(endPoint#78)])
      +- *(1) Project [endPoint#78, outcome#80]
         +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(outcome#80) && NOT (outcome#80 = success))
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[endPoint#78,count#79L,outcome#80]
```

window `explain`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [endPoint#78, (cast(count#79L as double) / cast(total#1016L as double)) AS failureRate#1021]
+- *(2) Filter (isnotnull(outcome#80) && (outcome#80 = failure))
   +- Window [sum(count#79L) windowspecdefinition(endPoint#78, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS total#1016L], [endPoint#78]
      +- *(1) Sort [endPoint#78 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(endPoint#78, 200)
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[endPoint#78,count#79L,outcome#80]
```

Pivot explain: (not as efficient)

```
df_failure_rate.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78], functions=[pivotfirst(outcome#80, sum(`count`)#89L, success, failure, 0, 0)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(endPoint#78, 200)
   +- HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78], functions=[partial_pivotfirst(outcome#80, sum(`count`)#89L, success, failure, 0, 0)])
      +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78, outcome#80], functions=[sum(count#79L)])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(endPoint#78, outcome#80, 200)
            +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[endPoint#78, outcome#80], functions=[partial_sum(count#79L)])
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[endPoint#78,count#79L,outcome#80]
```

`when` answer `explain`: (very efficient if the data set is small, as it doesn't filter out 'success' results.)

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[end_point#1039], functions=[sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = failure) THEN count#79L END), sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = success) THEN count#79L END)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(end_point#1039, 200)
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[end_point#1039], functions=[partial_sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = failure) THEN count#79L END), partial_sum(CASE WHEN (outcome#80 = success) THEN count#79L END)])
      +- *(1) Project [endPoint#78 AS end_point#1039, count#79L, outcome#80]
         +- Scan ExistingRDD[endPoint#78,count#79L,outcome#80]
```

Comment: i'd suggest to also look at the logical plan or optimized logical plan with `explain(True)`.